# Categorical variable

Tags: r, combinations, categorical-data

I have a dataset which has disease A as 1 or 0, B as 1 or 0 and C as 1 or 0. I want to make a new column as Any disease, D where all these 1 and 0 will be present, how can I do it?

I am very new in R programming.

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow! Beginners are welcome, but we expect a certain amount of effort to be expended on attempting to solve your own problem prior to a question being posted. We dont write code for you although we are very willing to help you fix issues with code you have written. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I think you want all the disease in one column with their respective scores.

Lets say yoour datset is

```
dat = data.frame(A = rep(c(1,0), 4), 
           B = rep(c(0,1), 4),
           C = rep(c(1,0), 4))
```

Then you can use `gather` to get all the diseases in one column.

```
    library(tidyr)
    dat1 = gather(dat)
    
    dat1 = `colnames<-`(dat1, c("Disease", "Score"))
    
   Disease Score
1        A     1
2        A     0
3        A     1
4        A     0
5        A     1
6        A     0
7        A     1
8        A     0
9        B     0
10       B     1
11       B     0
12       B     1
13       B     0
14       B     1
15       B     0
16       B     1
17       C     1
18       C     0
19       C     1
20       C     0
21       C     1
22       C     0
23       C     1
24       C     0
```